# How do I put a link to a screenshot on my homescreen?

Tags: screenshots

I have a screenshot of my university timetable I want to be able to easily access on my Android phone. How can I create a link to this on my homescreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this widget : [Photo Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.style_7.photo_widget_7), which allows you to put images on your home screen. Or the application [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.widget&hl=fr) but it is a bit heavy for what you need however this app is very useful.

Hope this will help

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. The photo gallery widget used to be a part of stock Android, but I haven't seen it in a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Many devices (or their pre-installed launchers) already ship with a widget called "image frame" or similar, which is what I'd check first: Open your app drawer, and check for available widgets which have a name like that – then add it to your homwscreen (when found). It should ask you for an image to put into the "frame", and you should be able to select your time table.